# need the rows with a unique value on certain columns but date column doesn't help?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, select, distinct

I have a table with multiple records by each employee. I need to find all the records by employee where any of the columns values changes. For example, I have the following data for George:

```
CREATE TABLE tableName
(
     NAME   varchar(300),
     HOME   varchar(300),
     CURRENT    varchar(300),
     EFFECTIVE_DATE     varchar(300),
     NOT_TO_EXCEED_DATE     varchar(300),
     FLAG   varchar(300),
     GRADE  varchar(300),
     POSITION   varchar(300),
     LAST_PAY_PERIOD_PAID   varchar(255)
);
```

```
INSERT INTO tableName ( NAME , HOME , CURRENT , EFFECTIVE_DATE , NOT_TO_EXCEED_DATE , FLAG , GRADE , POSITION , LAST_PAY_PERIOD_PAID )
VALUES
    ('GEORGE', '610422', '610422', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'N', '15', 'SUPERVISOR  ACCOUNTANT', '202107'),
    ('GEORGE', '610422', '630100', '11/10/2019', '11/6/2021', 'Y', '15', 'SUPERVISOR  ACCOUNTANT', '202105'),
    ('GEORGE', '610422', '610422', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'N', '15', 'SUPERVISOR  ACCOUNTANT', '202105'),
    ('GEORGE', '610422', '630100', '11/10/2019', '11/6/2021', 'Y', '15', 'SUPERVISOR  ACCOUNTANT', '202103'),
    ('GEORGE', '610422', '630100', '11/10/2019', '11/6/2021', 'Y', '14', ' ACCOUNTANT', '202026'),
    ('GEORGE', '610124', '630100', '11/10/2019', '11/6/2021', 'Y', '14', ' ACCOUNTANT', '202023'),
    ('GEORGE', '610124', '630100', '11/10/2019', '11/6/2021', 'Y', '14', ' ACCOUNTANT', '202024'),
    ('GEORGE', '610422', '630100', '11/10/2019', '11/6/2021', 'Y', '14', ' ACCOUNTANT', '202025'),
    ('GEORGE', '610422', '630100', '11/10/2019', '11/6/2021', 'Y', '14', ' ACCOUNTANT', '202025'),
    ('GEORGE', '610124', '630100', '11/10/2019', '11/6/2021', 'Y', '14', ' ACCOUNTANT', '202023'),
    ('GEORGE', '610124', '630100', '11/10/2019', '11/6/2021', 'Y', '14', ' ACCOUNTANT', '202024'),
    ('GEORGE', '610422', '630100', '11/10/2019', '11/6/2021', 'Y', '15', 'SUPERVISOR  ACCOUNTANT', '202104'),
    ('GEORGE', '610422', '610422', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'N', '15', 'SUPERVISOR  ACCOUNTANT', '202106'),
    ('GEORGE', '610124', '630100', '11/10/2019', '11/6/2021', 'Y', '14', ' ACCOUNTANT', '202025'),
    ('GEORGE', '610422', '630100', '11/10/2019', '11/6/2021', 'Y', '14', ' ACCOUNTANT', '202101'),
    ('GEORGE', '610422', '610422', 'NULL', 'NULL', 'N', '15', 'SUPERVISOR  ACCOUNTANT', '202108'),
    ('GEORGE', '610422', '630100', '11/10/2019', '11/6/2021', 'Y', '14', ' ACCOUNTANT', '202102'),
    ('GEORGE', '610422', '630100', '11/10/2019', '11/6/2021', 'Y', '14', ' ACCOUNTANT', '202102'),
    ('GEORGE', '610422', '630100', '11/10/2019', '11/6/2021', 'Y', '15', 'SUPERVISOR  ACCOUNTANT', '202103');
```

How do I get the following result data set?

```
NAME,HOME,CURRENT,EFFECTIVEDATE,NOTTOEXCEEDDATE,FLAG,GRADE,POSITION,LASTPAYPERIODPAID
GEORGE,610124,630100,11/10/2019,11/6/2021,Y,14, ACCOUNTANT,202023
GEORGE,610422,630100,11/10/2019,11/6/2021,Y,15,SUPERVISOR  ACCOUNTANT,202103
GEORGE,610422,610422,NULL,NULL,N,15,SUPERVISOR  ACCOUNTANT,202105
```

So far I can only get the result data set by doing a Select Distinct without the `LAST_PAY_PERIOD_PAID` column. Given that I do need to know when has the record changed based on the pay period, as soon as I add this column I get the first table all over again.

When there are different values for two records that are the same otherwise, the most recent `LAST_PAY_PERIOD` would be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding the objective but, to take the data that you helpfully provided in the `INSERT` and determine both the period when the record changed *and* the most recently paid period, you can do this:

```
SELECT 
  tn.[name], 
  tn.[home], 
  tn.[current], 
  tn.[effective_date], 
  tn.[not_to_exceed_date], 
  tn.[flag], 
  tn.[grade], 
  TRIM(tn.[position]) as [position],
  MIN(tn.[last_pay_period_paid]) as [first_pay_period_paid], 
  MAX(tn.[last_pay_period_paid]) as [recent_pay_period_paid]
FROM 
  [dbo].[tableName] tn
GROUP BY 
  tn.[name], 
  tn.[home],
  tn.[current],
  tn.[effective_date],
  tn.[not_to_exceed_date],
  tn.[flag],
  tn.[grade],
  TRIM(tn.[position])
```

This will give you the following output:

[image: Output of the GROUP BY]

Note that there are two records for `ACCOUNTANT`. This is because there are two distinct values in `home`. Not sure if this is due to a typo in the sample data or if the column is even necessary. Either way ... this may give you the information you seek.

Comment: would i also be able to filter upon the newly created last_pay_period_paid and/or recent_pay_period_paid columns? if its possible could you let me know how?

Comment: @Jen Rather than leaving "thank you" in a comment, vote on answers and accept the one you found most helpful. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers in the help. If you have a new, related, or follow-up question, feel free to ask it separately.

Comment: To filter on these columns you would need to wrap the query above into a subquery. `SELECT * FROM ({above query}) tmp WHERE tmp.[first_pay_period_paid] >= {period}`. **However**, this is not a great way forward for tables with lots of data. If you are going to be doing this for a medium-to-large company, then there are better ways to solve the problem.